# How to insert value key-value pair in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to insert a value key pair in an array in php. The code is given below but the issue is that it is giving error  **Illegal offset type** on the line where I'm trying to push data. $request_url is the data coming from API.

```
$response = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
//make different array of images of small , medium and large size
$array_features = array();
$array_smallImages = array();
$array_mediumImage = array();
$array_largeImage = array();

foreach($response->Items->Item as $item){
    echo $item->ItemAttributes->Title.'<br>';   
    echo $item->ASIN.'<br>';
    $asin = $item->ASIN;
    echo $item->DetailPageURL.'<br>';
    echo $item->ItemAttributes->Manufacturer.'<br>';
    $small_img = $item->SmallImage->URL;
    $array_smallImages[$asin] = $small_img; 
    //$array_smallImages =  $item->SmallImage->URL;
    echo $item->MediumImage->URL.'<br>';
    echo $item->LargeImage->URL.'<br>';
    //echo $item->ItemAttributes->Manufacturer.'<br>';  
    echo 'Features:'.'<br>';
    foreach($item->ItemAttributes->Feature as $fea){
    //  $array_features[$item->ASIN] = $fea;
        echo $fea.'<br>';
    }
```

**$array_smallImages[$asin] = $small_img;** is the line on which error is coming Warning: Illegal offset type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a new key value pair in array in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524484/how-to-insert-a-new-key-value-pair-in-array-in-php)

Comment: @KrisRoofe used that method and getting error. I'm here talking about the error.

Comment: your $asin should be string or num. not object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php - How do I fix this illegal offset type error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732451/php-how-do-i-fix-this-illegal-offset-type-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key

Use `trim($asin)` before   `$array_smallImages[$asin] = $small_img;`